# Horizontally center a DIV in page

Tags: html, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winjs

I'm trying to center a div, which is the Microsoft pubCenter AdControl for Windows 8 apps in HTML5/JavaScript.

```
    <div id="myAd" style="; top: 0%; width: 292px; height: 60px; z-index: 1"
        data-win-control="MicrosoftNSJS.Advertising.AdControl"
        data-win-options="{applicationId: 'exampleAdId', adUnitId: 'exampleAdUnit'}">
    </div>
```

How would I center a div horizontally so it is always in the middle of a page?

Comment: may want to look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670025/css-to-centralise-a-html5-div-at-the-bottom-of-the-screen/16674978#16674978)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use css only

```
left:50%;margin-left:-146px;
```

the point is to set margin left as half of the div width

Comment: Or use `margin:0 auto`... Much simpler.

Answer (score 19):

Add `margin:auto` in your `style=""` tag and that should do the trick.

Other possibility, `align=center`

Answer (score 4):

you can use simply this class to absolute center

```
.ab_center
{
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    background-color:#27f305;
    position:absolute;
    margin:auto;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

Example fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/devesh_dc/dzyvmt0o/

Answer (score 0):

Found on other site for HTML5, C# and VS2015.  Add to css: `#wrapper { width: 600px;margin: auto;}` and wrap your content with:
   `<form id="form1">
   <div id="wrapper">
       Content
   </div>
</form>`

Answer (score -6):

you can use `align='center'` in `<div>` tag

Comment: This is not supported by html5